# COUNTIFS Greater/Less Than Logic Always Returns 0

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

We're trying to create a sort of filtering system that allows us to filter spreadsheet entries that include a start and end date. We'd like to filter these entries by date (start and end) so we can pull dynamic averages.

We're almost there, though it seems the logic for 'greater/lesser than this date' is not working properly, the result is always 0 after applying the greater/lesser than logic. We tried using just greater-than/lesser-than themselves during troubleshooting and both result in 0. Below is the formula we are currently using. It works as intended until we try to filter between dates:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$22:$A, B1, $B$22:$B, "Live", $E$22:$E, ">=" &$G$2, $E$22:$E, "<=" &$H$2)
```

`$A$22:$A`: Range of entries

`B1`: Entry name we're comparing against

`$B$22:$B`: Range of entry statuses

`"Live"`: status we're comparing against

`$E$22:$E`: Range of dates

`&$G$2`: The 'From' date

`&$H$2`: The 'To' date

The formula works great until we start trying to filter by date. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you add any information around what "no working properly" means?  Perhaps a sample of data w/ the expected results vs the actual results?  Just saying "it's not working", the best guess is something along the lines of "probably because you're doing it wrong".

Comment: Fair enough, @sous2817! This slipped my mind. The formula does not error, it just returns 0.

Comment: Maybe share a link to a sample sheet.

Comment: make sure dates are really dates and not text formatted as dates.  Make sure your search criteria are dates and not really text formatted as dates.  For whatever reason, I've found that I get better results when my search criteria is the Int equivalent to a date rather than the date itself.  I get it's probably something I'm doing wrong, but sometimes you just go with what works and promise yourself you'll sort it out later.

Comment: How are you filtering? Auto or Advanced?

Comment: Thanks all for your input. I'm including a link to a sample sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QkuaI6Kw0Of3HIkckHZqoyymAdYJyzjRNMhk7Aj7LQs/edit#gid=924947548

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(A22:A, B1, B22:B, "Live", E22:E*1, ">=" &G2, E22:E*1, "<=" &H2))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works, thank you! I was able to take it from there. What was preventing my original formula from working correctly?

Comment: could be empty cells adjacent to non-emty columns or also could be that some cell(s) is formatted as plain text